# How to convert a 3 column tuple without header to a two key single value dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have two tuples, say:

```
l = (water, lily , 6)
m = (history , book, 5)
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary with 2 keys and a single value.

```
dict = {(water,lily): 6} {(history, book) : 5}
```

for the multiple line tuples in python.

How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```
l = [('water', 'lily' , 6), ('history' , 'book', 5)]
x = {(one, two): three for one, two, three in l}
print(x) # Prints {('water', 'lilly'): 6, ('history', 'book'): 5)}
```

Comment: I need to update these converted values to a dictionary and I'm having issues with the length as it shows for each row being one rather than counting the whole key - value pair in dictionary

Comment: I am confused by your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @MadhuSibi This matches the answer you requested. Can you provided another example with what you want?  Do you want to use `water` or `lilly` as a key instead of them combined as a tuple?

Comment: There has been  an indentation error . sorted now! Thank you!